# Query regarding ColorSetting trait in Google Device Actions

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-smart-home

I am not able to query google assistant about "what color is my light", the documentation at the following web page says that ColorSetting trait has the ability for a light to asked about what color it is set to but I am not able to accomplish it. Please help...

URL:

https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/colorsetting

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what were the results?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that your sync response is valid in the code validator:
https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/colorsetting#validator

2) Open your Google Home app from your phone and select your device: check if the app shows the right device state and check that you received a query request and that you answered with the color.

3) Use Stackdriver logging https://cloud.google.com/logging/?hl=it to view if there's any error in Google Cloud Platform.

4) You can compare your JSON responses with the documentation examples using an on-line file merge tool to be sure that is correct.