# Does Google support querying smart light color?

Tags: node.js, google-smart-home, google-assistant

We are working on integrating a smart device with google assistant. This device has a light that has the ability to set its color as well as report it's color back in a query response.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/query

We are able to set the light color verbally using Google home app or the Nest smart speaker, however it's proving difficult to get it to report back the color of the light verbally.

We have performed all the checks in this answer [Query regarding ColorSetting trait in Google Device Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967787/query-regarding-colorsetting-trait-in-google-device-actions) all pass, but still the same result.

Also querying two different brands of smart light yields the same results - no color reporting.

At this point I'm wondering if this feature is not yet implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can verbally give commands/requests to the Google Assistant to set the smart light color to change (supporting RGB or HSV color model). Refer to the following documentation for more details https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/colorsetting#action.devices.commands.colorabsolute

Right now there are no provisions made to query the google assistant verbally to know the light color. Our internal teams are working on including these features in our ecosystem in the future.